# calculate month over month value in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to calculate month over month for below data

Input

```
D‌ate        platform     Value
0‌9/04/2018     X          2345
0‌9/05/2018     X          2678
0‌9/06/2018     X          2673
1‌0/05/2018     X          2876
1‌0/06/2018     X          2789
```

Output Would be

```
D‌ate        platform     Value  Prev month Value
0‌9/04/2018     X          2345  Null
0‌9/05/2018     X          2678  Null
0‌9/06/2018     X          2673  Null
1‌0/05/2018     X          2876   2678
1‌0/06/2018     X          2789   2673
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want a `left join`:

```
select t.*, tprev.value
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.platform = t.platform and
        tprev.date = t.date - interval '1 month';
```

Note that this is ANSI/ISO standard syntax.  In SQL Server the last condition would be:

```
        tprev.date = dateadd(month, -1, t.date);
```

Also note that "previous month" is not well defined.  What is one month before Mar 31?

Comment: I want Month Over Month change,Previous month is just to identify column name.

Comment: can i use lag function to calculate mom?